# Get the stored date in symfony2 doctrine mongodb

Tags: symfony, doctrine-mongodb

I have created a console command page in my bundle for cronjob.
Here is the code

> class MyCommand extends Command {
>
> ```
> protected function configure()
> {
>     $this
>         ->setName('cron:item_email')
>         ->setDescription('product notification for customer that reserved');
> }
>
> protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
> {
>
>     $this->container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();
>     $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
>     $wishlist = $em->getRepository('xxxxBundle:Wishlist')->findAll();
>     foreach($wishlist as $wish){
>         if($wish->getReservedDate()){
>       //  $output->writeln($wish->getId());
>         $output->writeln($wish->getReservedDate());
>     }
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Here I am retrieving mongo db date "$wish->getReservedDate()"
But I am getting the output like this

```
2013-07-03 13:46:42
3
Europe/Berlin
```

How I get the date only for ex: 2013-07-03 13:46:42

Comment: I assume `getReservedDate()` returns a `DateTime` object. Why don't you just `$wish->getResveredDate()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$wish->getReservedDate()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s')

Also as a side note, the ID has the date stored in it also.

Just a FYI